# Displaying Javascript response object in MODAL

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have created a view as:

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top:20px">
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-lg-4" style="padding-top:20px;">
            <div class="card" style="width:18rem">
                <img src="@Url.Content(item.ImagePath)" class="card-img-top" />
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h5 class="card-title">@item.ProductName</h5>
                        <p style="color:crimson">  &ensp;( Rs @item.ProductPrice )</p>
                    </div>
                    @*<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#loginModal" data-toggle="modal">Details</a>*@
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btndetails"  data-product-id="@item.Id" @*data-target="#loginModal" data-toggle="modal"*@>Details</button>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    }
</div>
```

when I click the Details button the JavaScript function is invoked in which I am making an ajax call to Admin controller and GetProduct actionMethod which takes an Id, Gets the data with that id and returns a JSON object:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btndetails").on("click", function () {
        $.ajax({

            method: "POST",
            url: "/Admin/GetProduct/" + $(this).attr("data-product-id"),
            success: function (response) {

            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Its all working correct until here, I get the object in success function response object but now I want to display that object in a MODAL that I have created as:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title"> Details</h4>
                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm())
                        {


                        }
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So in short I want to display the object I received in JavaScript Response object in MODAL I created.

Comment: so wouldn't it be easier after your get call when you receive your json object just clear modal-body then append html from your get into modal body?

Comment: sorry sir, can you please illustrate it with an example, i do not know how to do what you are asking to.

Comment: display specifically where in the modal ? A place holder div ? an input element ? You can update the DOM inside the `success` handler of your ajax call.

Comment: so maybe something like this  https://jsfiddle.net/bhd03afg/2/

Answer (score 0):

Wait it looks like you are trying to use ASP.Net rendering engine (which is generated during request on SERVER side) to render a result of an AJAX request which is performed by the client.

Sorry friend but that's just not going to work.

I mean if you really have to use ASP.Net to render that form, I'd suggest creating a separate view which just returns the form (Html.BeginForm()) section, then use jquery to paste that into the modal-body class as a raw html.

```
$('.modal-body').html(response);
```

It'd be a really bad solution from a MVC point of view and I'd advise against that, but it'd get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I am succesful in woring out the solution as :
**I used getElementById and value functions to get the MODAL input field and then used value function to set the values in response object to MODAL input fields.**
My AJAX Call is :

```
$(".btndetails").on("click", function () {
        $.ajax({

            method: "POST",
            url: "/Admin/GetProduct/" + $(this).attr("data-product-id"),
            success: function (response) {
                var pName = document.getElementById("pName");
                pName.value = response.ProductName;

                var pPrice = document.getElementById("pPrice");
                pPrice.value = response.ProductPrice;

                var pDPrice = document.getElementById("pDPrice");
                pDPrice.value = response.DiscountPrice;

                var imgTitle = document.getElementById("imgTitle");
                imgTitle.value = response.ImageTitle;

                var stock = document.getElementById("stock");
                stock.value = response.Stock;

                var description = document.getElementById("description");
                description.value = response.Description;

                var img = document.getElementById("img");
                img.value = response.ImagePath;
                $("#img").attr("src", img);
            }

        });

    });
```

And the modal i created below it is :

```
<div class="modal-body">
                        <form>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Product Name</label>
                                    <input id="pName" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img src="" id="img" width="150px" height="150px" style="float:right" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Product Price</label>
                                    <input id="pPrice" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Discount Price</label>
                                    <input id="pDPrice" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Image Title</label>
                                    <input id="imgTitle" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Quantity in stock</label>
                                    <input id="stock" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Description</label>
                                    <input id="description" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">

                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Category</label>
                                        @Html.DropDownList("Category", new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Category"], "Id", "CategoryName"), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Anfinal outpur is like :[image: Click to view final output]